# How to parse JSON in BASH without using any external libraries

Tags: json, bash

```
{"name": "max", "Age": "21", "height": "5.9", "city": "Chicago", "State": "Illinois"}
```

The desired output after stripping away the spaces, braces and the quotes:

```
name:max
age:21
height:5.9
city:Chicago
state:Illinois
```

I want to achieve this using only BASH and not using any external libraries. I have this so far:

```
sed 's/\r/\n\"//g' | tr -d '{}' | tr , '\n'
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not meant to be a code writing service. Please attempt to write some code and get started with your task, then come back and ask questions when you get stuck.

Comment: In his defense he may have been asking for the bash equivalent to php json_decode (), in his ignorance not knowing it didn't exist

Comment: @BrianGottier I just updated the post

Comment: Why the unnecessary requirement that you cant use some other tool? Use the right tool for the job. Bash and other shell languages are not general-purpose parsers and are not designed to read and manipulate JSON. Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) if you want to work with JSON from the command line.

Comment: Visit http://json.org and review the specification of a string.  Note that `{`. `}` and `,` can appear inside a string; so can `\"`, and there are other escape sequences.  These are the things that make your approach substantially infeasible — to be reliable, you need a tool that understands these nuances.  Also, what should happen if one of the elements of the object is an array of objects.  (It isn't immediately clear to me why carriage return should be mapped to newline and double quote, but we can let that slide for the time being.)

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/g;s/"//g;s/{//g;s/}//g' filename
```